# how to find a list in a bunch of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I want a way to make it so that I can use list B to find out if a copy of it's self exists in list A.
I want a way to make it so that I can use list B to find out if a copy of it's self exists in list A.

this is the way data a has been collected:

```
for i in range(len(fsa)):
    if fsa[i] < fsb[i]:
        kol.append('1')
    else:
        kol.append('0')

start = 0
end = len(fsa)
j = [ ]
for x in range(start, end, 6):
    m = fsb[x:x+6]
    t = kol[x:x+6]
    if m[0] < m[-1]:
        t.append('up')
    else:
        t.append('down')
    j.append(t)

counter = Counter(tuple(j) for j in j)
for members, count, in counter.items():
    print(list(members), count)
```

output:

```
listA = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down'] 2
['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up'] 2
['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up'] 1
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up'] 2
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up'] 1
['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down'] 1
['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down'] 1
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up'] 1
```

this is how data b was collected:

```
for _ in range(num):
    inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(inner)
    lok.append(inner)
    time.sleep(20)#the hour
print(lok)

lokk = []
num = 7
for _ in range(num):
    inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(inner)
    lokk.append(inner)
    time.sleep(20)
print(lokk)
```

output:

```
listB = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

list A also shows how many times that particular list has appeared

so I want a way to first find the repeating list of list B in list A, secondly to select the one with the most repetitions in the case that there are multiple versions of it.

I tried a bunch of things but non really helped as i am still quite new at coding

Comment: Hi. Your code does not seem to be formatted correctly and is a bit confusing. Is that python code or pseudocode?

Comment: This code has several syntax errors.  Please fix.

Comment: Already mentioned, but your listA is not a list! listA =[ ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2], ... ] would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

As many pointed out, the code provided is not properly formatted, so I made some assumptions. Here is a half-solution to get you unstuck, try to modify this to get what you want. You will learn more by modifying this code than if I were to give you the final solution.

```
from collections import Counter  # for comparing lists' content
from typing import List  # for annotations

listA = [
  ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up'],
  ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up'],
  ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down'],
  ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down'],
  ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up'],
]

listB = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']

def find_match(metrix: List[List[str]], list_: List[str]) -> List[List[str]]:
  list_counter = Counter(list_)

  # Solution 1: Pythonic solution
  matches = [match for match in metrix if Counter(match[:-1]) == list_counter]

  # Solution 2: beginner friendly solution
  # matches = []
  # for m_list in metrix:
  #   if Counter(m_list[:-1]) == list_counter:
  #     matches.append(m_list)
  return matches

# Complexities
# if n == metrix.length and m == metrix[0].length; then
# Time: O(nm);
# Space: O(nm);

print(find_match(listA, listB))
# outputs: [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up']]
```

Comment: use this link to modify this code, you will need an account. https://replit.com/join/ayfwlqksbc-darior 

Happy hacking! :}

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that works. Not sure if it's exactly what you want, but you can modify it to fit your needs.

Note that it assumes listB has the same length as the first part of each of listA elements (before "up"/"down").

```
listA =[ 
        ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2],
        ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 2],
        ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 1],
        ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 2],
        ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 1],
        ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
        ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 1],
        ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 1]
        ]
    
listB = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']

listC = ['0','0','0','0','0','0']


def find_list(list1,list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i,l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)]==list1:
            if l[-1]>occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]
    if index == -1:
        return "The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one."
    else:
        return f"The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index {index} with a number of occurences equal to {occ}."
    
    
print(find_list(listB, listA))

# The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index 7 with a number of occurences equal to 1.

print(find_list(listC, listA))

# The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one.
```

Comment: The code runs but it does not seem to go over all my lists as it says "The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one." when the lists is there...what can I do there?

Comment: Do you have an example of situation that fails ?

Comment: when i pass the code and substitute accordingly for some reason my list can not be analyzed

Comment: input: 
counter = Counter(tuple(j) for j in j)
for members, count, in counter.items():
    g = list(members), count
    print(g)
    koll = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 2]

Comment: I can't get the code in your comment to work: what is j ?

Comment: is there another platform i can speak to you on because i am out of questions attempts on this one and i cant explain everything